# What are these pipe and wires at the side of my house?

Tags: electrical, plumbing

I moved into a new build and I noticed my dog tried digging up a hole next to my house. And now I see a single white pipe that’s capped at the end. There is also a single black wire that ends but isn’t connected to anything. I saw small bits and pieces of wires in the backyard but not sure if it’s related to this. Any idea what this might be for?

[image]

Comment: That looks like cat 5 or 6....probably buried to future proof the new build and with direct burial coating  ,  since we don't know what's inside the white pipe, no comment.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson look again, closer - green white red (and presumably black, but hard to see) - it looks like a hunk of cordage (power cord or extension cord wire.) Red is not a color you see in 4-pair communication cable, and the thick rubber jacket is very likely some relative of SJO cordage. It is not cable that should be buried - technically, not even cable, since it's cordage. As for the question, start digging to find the answer (& let your dog help to make the dog happy!) - or, call the builder, as it's a new build.

Comment: Irrigation controller wires and piping?

Comment: Why not ask the builder.  Probably a good idea to check to see if there is any voltage at those wires before someone or their dog gets hurt.

Comment: Irrigation was my first thought, too, but really, we're just guessing. Ask your builder, it'll be much easier and more accurate.

Comment: A closer better focused picture of the cable might improve the wild guesses slightly.  If you can find the other end that would also be helpful.  If it's for irrigation the other end might be in an in-ground box.  Maybe with a green plastic cover.

Comment: If trying again on the picture front, close and focussed on the end of the cable, and also go for the *text on the side* of the cord/cable (typically just indented, rarely also colored in) which identifies exactly what it is (repeats every 2-3 feet.)